# Issue in searching for the existing Jobs stored in DBJobStore of Quartz scheduler

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am using DB Job Store of Quartz scheduler to schedule my runs on a periodic basis. Inorder to get all the existing Jobs and their states , I am using the following code :

```
    for(String jobGroupName : scheduler.getJobGroupNames() {
        for(String jobName : scheduler.getjobNames(jobGroupName) {
            JobDetail jobDetail = scheduler.getJobDetail(jobName, jobGroupName);
            Trigger[] triggers = scheduler.getTriggersOfJob(jobName, jobGroupName); 
            Trigger trigger = triggers[0];
            int jobState = scheduler.getTriggerState(trigger.getName(), trigger.getGroup());
        } 
    }
```

I have also implemented the Job Interface as follows

```
    public class jobImpl implements Job {
        public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg) {
          // My Code 
        }
    }
```

When ever I call the code for getting the existing Jobs and their states (the first code sample ) , the execute method in jobImpl gets triggered.

Can someone help me out with this ?

@Tomasz

Here is the stack Trace :

```
      java.lang.NullPointerException 
      [junit] at com.JobImpl.execute(JobImpl.java:24)                 
      [junit] at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216) 
      [junit] at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:549)
```

Comment: Are you able to set a breakpoint inside `jobImpl.execute()` and paste stacktrace (even screenshot) from your debugger? I want to see how this method gets triggered...

Comment: Hi Tomasz ,                                                                       Here is the stack Trace :                                           java.lang.NullPointerException
    [junit]     at com.JobImpl.execute(JobImpl.java:24)
    [junit]     at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)
    [junit]     at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:549)

Comment: Which version of Quartz are you using? Also are you sure your code triggers the job? The stacktrace looks like an ordinary scheduled job execution. Which line of code from your question triggers the job? Can you comment them out selectively?

Comment: I am using Quartz - 1.0.   The  job is being triggered from multiple places in the code.  i.e.,. LINE 2 (scheduler.getJobNames()) ,Line 3 (scheduler.getJobDetail()) , line 4, line 6.   As I comment out each line and check ,   the number of invocations is reduced.  With just the first for loop and nothing inside it, the Job class is not invoked at all.  So, it looks like the call is being triggered from this code itself.